# Applescript - Convert String to File Reference

Tags: applescript

I can't seem to figure out how to convert my string to a file

reference.

```
--savestring4 is the directory listing "/Volumes/Jobs/Artwork/Howard Keys/7-17-14/Happy_Keys/KW_CHK1-CHK49"
--myCode1 is the filename "845849005126"

set p to savestring4 & "/" & myCode1 & ".eps"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
set theTextItems to text items of p
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
set p2 to theTextItems as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}


set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":Volumes:"
set theTextItems2 to text items of p2
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set p to theTextItems2 as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}

set mybarcodepath to a as alias
```

I keep getting and error on the last command saying it cant find the file

return p outputs:

"Jobs:Artwork:Howard Keys:7-17-14:Happy_Keys:KW_CHK1-CHK49:845849005126.eps"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a posix path string to an alias like this:

```
set filePosixPath to "/Volumes/Jobs/Artwork/Howard Keys/7-17-14/Happy_Keys/KW_CHK1-CHK49"
set fileRef to (POSIX file filePosixPath) as alias
```

Comment: Why are you using the Finder in your second line of code? The posix file command is a standard addition to applescript, not a Finder command... I'd suggest removing it.

Comment: In addition you might point out to the poster that he can just use "posix file". There's no need to additionally coerce that to an "alias". I know he asked how to make an alias but really he doesn't need the alias when he uses the posix file command... that should work wherever he needs to use the file reference.

Comment: Hi regulus6633. Finder was left over from a script debugger shortcut... my fault.